# Solr exact search with blank character AND a wildcard

Tags: solr, wildcard

I got a problem with solr search. I want to search a string with a blank character within and a wildcard in the end. the only way that i found was to put the string in quotes. but if I do like this and i can´t put a wildcard in the end.

so is there any way i can search for "foo bar"* ?

thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

you can try escaping the white space `field:foo\ bar*`

[Wildcard Queries](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries) :-
Note that wildcards are not supported within quoted phrases. They will be treated as if they were white space.