# How do you specify a filter query with Solrj with embedded whitespace?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am using `SolrJ` to search `Solr`.

My application works fine until I receive a filter query with embedded whitespace

I have tried the following formats

```
String filterQuery_1 = "\"xxx xxx xxx\"*";
String filterQuery_2 = "xxx\\ xxx\\ xxx*";
String filterQuery_3 = "(xxx xxx xxx)*";
```

none give satisfactory results

They either result in no filtering being applied at all
or I get rows that do not appear to have any relationship to what I have filtered on

How do you search `solr` with `solrj` with filter strings that have embedded whitespace?

****** UPDATE 0001 ******

All the text fields I am attempting to search with embedded blanks are defined as follows:-

```
<field name="TEXT_FIELD_00001" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

These fields contain postal address details.

e.g.

```
     123 My Road
     My Town
     My County
     My Country
     AA1  1AA
```

Comment: What values are you searching for and how is the field defined? Wildcard queries are _not_ analyzed, so if the field is tokenized or processed in any way, wildcard queries will only match if the wildcarded part matches the start of an actual token.

Comment: Behavior are depended of your schema and which QueryParser do you use. Can you add you schema (just part where you define field what are you trying to filter) ?

Comment: @iMysak how do I identify my QueryParser?

Comment: @Hector, just ensure deftype parameter(if you use/override it)  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThedefTypeParameter . Keep in mind that you need check your Request handler https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler.  Solr have a lot of RequestHandlers (configured in solrconfig.xml) you need to check only one what you use("name" attribute should match you request uri). By default it is "/select". Default QueryParser - The Standard Query Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you trying something like this  - [Solr exact search with blank character AND a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749688/solr-exact-search-with-blank-character-and-a-wildcard)

This is works, but depends of configuration schema(field definition) this can be broken.

Can you try check this querying Solr manually(from admin panel or using REST api)? Just to avoid any possibility of incorect escaping what can SolrJ can do. If the filter query works correctly we can try investigate issue with SolrJ. Otherwise - you should review your schema.